# Postgresql password reset, I have two versions of PG installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, passwords

I am on mac os 12.5 Monterey.  I type in psql and I get

psql -U postgres
Password for user postgres:
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

I am looking for pg_hba.conf on postgres 9.3, my LS for the PG 9.3 directory looks like this

:9.3 chriswilson$ ls
3rd_party_licenses.txt      data                installer           pgAdmin3.app            share
Library             doc             lib             pg_env.sh           stackbuilder.app
bin             include             license.txt         scripts             uninstall-postgresql.app

I have found the pg_hba.conf for the postgres@14 I installed with homebrew and all my permissions were set to trust.  I have tried running uninstall-postgresql.app and nothing happens.   I used locate pg.hba and all I can find are pg_hba.conf.sample not the actual pg_hba.

Comment: Now I am getting the error psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  database "chriswilson" does not exist.

 I found the pg_hba.conf file in Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/data/pg_hba.conf and switched the md5 to trust

Comment: I guess my rails app works in development with postgresql now.  So I think my question is answered.  I still cannot login as user postgres.  And I still cannot uninstall PG 9.3, but as long as rails works I should be good to go.

Comment: You' serm to have basic trouble setting up and authenticating with PostgreSQL. We don't know how you set up your system. Some quality time with the documentation might help.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on 12.5.1 Monterey mac os(failed: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres") when opening Pgadmin4 even though the password was correct.

Fixed by downloading Postgres.app on https://postgresapp.com.
After hosting the server via Postgres.app the error on pgAdmin4 is gone.